# Cors error in spring boot on remote servers

Tags: reactjs, spring-boot

I am trying to deploy a simple spring boot back end server and React js front end application in a remote Ubuntu server using ssh. This program works fine in localhost. But when I deploy both front and back ends in remote Ubuntu server and try to access through my browser in my local machine it gives cors error, "Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at …".

[cors error at the browser console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/An4Kt.png)

Here is my code setup

**Back end**

Application.java

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class DemoApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
    }


    
    @Bean
    public FilterRegistrationBean<CorsFilter> simpleCorsFilter() {
        UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
        CorsConfiguration config = new CorsConfiguration();
        config.setAllowCredentials(true);
        config.setAllowedOrigins(Arrays.asList("http://localhost:3000"));
        config.setAllowedMethods(Collections.singletonList("*"));
        config.setAllowedHeaders(Collections.singletonList("*"));
        source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", config);
        FilterRegistrationBean<CorsFilter> bean = new FilterRegistrationBean<>(new 

CorsFilter(source));
            bean.setOrder(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE);
            return bean;
        }
}
```

controller.java

@RestController
public class TestController {

```
@GetMapping("/getTestData")
// @CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:3000")
public MyResponse getTestData(){
    return new MyResponse();
}
```

}

application.properties

```
server.port=8002
```

**Front End**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'


class App extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      error: null,
      data: '',

    };
  }

  async componentDidMount() {
    const responsedata = await fetch('http://localhost:8002/getTestData');
    const json = await responsedata.json();
    this.setState({ data: json.name });

  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <p>{this.state.data}</p>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
export default App;
```

I allowed port 3000 through ufw, any help would be appreciated…

Comment: Had it been an issue with your firewall, you wouldn't get a response at all.

Comment: @CodeWalker no there was non, i set  nginx in port 80. i just didn't want to involve nginx in this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Presuming the `@CrossOrigin` isn't doing the trick for you, give this a try.

```
@Bean
public WebMvcConfigurer corsConfigurer() {
    return new WebMvcConfigurer() {
        @Override
        public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
            registry.addMapping("/greeting-javaconfig").allowedOrigins("http://yourdomain.com:port");
        }
    };
}
```